# A thought experiment for gravitational waves

Tags: gravitational-waves

My question is:
I want to in a thought experiment, calculate the gravitational waves that are generated while I Shake my hands?

-A hand mass:~400 gr
& Frequency: 3 times per second.

Here is what I want to solve in this experiment:

1-Find h (strain)

2-Find flux (over 1 meter away from my hands as a source in impact of A = 1 cm square)

3-Find damping (for example after pass through a wall 10 meter away from my hands with 1 meter thickness)

Note: we have some equation that they can help us:

1-For calculating the strain and flux here is the formula: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/53547/50779

2-For calculating damping:
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/53899/50779

Comment: How is the flux observed 1-m away from a source affected by universal expansion\? (It isn't).  NOte that universal expansion and dark energy are two different things. Gravitational waves aren't damped significantly by matter (e.g. they pass through the Earth unhindered).

Comment: @ProfRob damping and pass through are two different things, when it is pass through a matter it os loose its a bit amplitude ( look at the link i mentioned above) , sure it is not block by matter but damp then continue both dust and matter can damp GW.  and flux is caculable in any distance in desired Area .  about hubble constant it only change the shape of wave but flux is energy per area , they are not related , we can caculate 4 parameter which i mentioned aboved .

Comment: Please summarise your question in the title, to help other people find it. Thank you.

Comment: @user438383 ok , i did

Comment: To a very large number of decimal places the answers will be 0, 0 and 0.

Comment: @JamesK we can not say zero , yes it is very very tiny but answering zero incorrect becuase equation and formula admit existing of such a spectrum, but in their own decimal ,  isn't it?